# Error during Edubuntu installation: process:226

Tags: installation, edubuntu

We recently introduced Edbuntu to a team of school teachers. One of them tried installing Edubuntu in their school computers and have reported us this problem. I have no answer for the problem. So can anyone help?

One of the teacher's wrote:
I was able to install edubuntu in some of the pc. But not able to install in PCs with celeron processor 2.40 GHz , 1GB RAM & HDD 40GB. Im getting error message:

```
process:226 -  Glib warning: getpwuid_r(): failed due to unknown user id(0)
```

Comment: How did you install Chethan was it from cd/dvd or USB stick?

Comment: Perhaps a corrupt Image. Did you try re-downloading the cd image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the installation was tried from a DVD since we had given a copy of Edubuntu in a DVD to all the participants. The teacher later contacted us and now the problem is solved. The solution was rather simple. He wrote like this:

> Sorry guys for disturbing u. I got the
>   solution for my problem....... i have
>   to press ALT and CTRL key when error
>   occurs. Thank you

Thanks from our side as well.